# Entity Framework with Offline Storage

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The essence of the situation comes down to the following:

- I have a data collection system that needs to constantly update to a
  central database.
- The database is connected via a somewhat flaky wifi connection (that 
  I can't get away from or fix)
- Due to the above the device needs to store the data locally as it
  could be anywhere from 30 seconds to 12 hours before the connection
  can be restored.
- The server is SQL Server 2000 (Customer is dragging feet about upgrading)
- The data collection runs on a number of Windows XP PCs

The current system uses Datasets and Diffgrams serialized to XML to deal with the local storage. I am wanting to rewrite the system using Entity Framework for my data access, however the ability to maintain an offline copy of the last few days data is essential as I need to protect against a power cut during a period of no network connectivity.

Any advice on the best approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Store to a local DB instance, and have a background process deal with the nitty-gritty of faulty connections with the main server.  This will effect your DB design because auto-incremented values can't work cross-server.

Comment: Having read the comments so far I think I'm going to leave the worms firmly in the can on this one until I can convince them to upgrade to 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Entity Framework won't directly help you with this. The Sync Framework is probably closer to what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608

Comment: Having read the comments so far I think I'm going to leave the worms firmly in the can on this one until I can convince them to upgrade to 2008 R2. Thanks for the help all.